# How to structure django models and query them with ease?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am building a Django web App that will count the total number of persons entering and exiting a school library in a day, week and year and then save to DB.

The Web App uses a camera that is controlled by OpenCv to show live feed on frontend (I have successfully implemented this already).

My problem is:

How can I design and structure my models to store each data by day, week, month and year?

And how can I query them to display them on different Bar Charts using chart.js?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used chart.js before but I think I can answer the first part of your question.

Consider this model from one of my projects for a "post" that a user can make on my webapp.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=photo_path, blank=False, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Using a "DateTimeField" (or alternatively a "DateField") you can pretty easily store timestamp information which can be filtered using standard python Date or DateTime object comparisons. In my example, I'm storing image files and text information.

For your case you could simply create a new "Person" model where each person is given a timestamp (and whatever other info you might want to store) and then using django querying you can count how many people match certain datetime parameters.

Note the Django Docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/) recommend :

> Don't use len() on QuerySets if all you want to do is determine the number of records in the set. It's much more efficient to handle a count at the database level, using SQL's SELECT COUNT(*), and Django provides a count() method for precisely this reason.

An example of how I'd approach your problem would be:

Models:

```
class Person(HabitModel):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    #whatever extra data you want on each person walking by

    @staticmethod
    def get_number_of_people(start_timestamp, end_timestamp):
        return Person.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=start_timestamp, timestamp__lt=end_timestamp)).count()
```

(Note the "__gte" and "__lt" are built-in for Django querying and imply [start_timestamp, end_timestamp) inclusive start time and exclusive endtime)

Now you should be able to store your data rather simply and quantify how many people objects were created in whatever timeframe you'd like!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have already resolved the issue.

Comment: Hey, glad to hear it! If my answer was correct, could you click the checkbox next to my response so someone else searching for a similar question can find their answer more easily? thanks!